# Differentiating exponential functions - is base e the only situation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

My maths book gives the example of;

Where $$ f = e^x $$ $$ f` = e^x $$

It only uses the example of base e in all of the questions so does that mean this is the only situation where the differential of an exponential function is the same as the original?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since
$$
Da^x=De^{x\ln a}=e^{x\ln a}\ln a=a^x\ln a,
$$
and the only $a$ for which $\ln a=1$ is $a=e$.

Comment: Errrrrrr. Could you explain those steps you did there?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy Does the intermediate step $D(e^{\ln a})^x$ help?  Then the exponents get multiplied.

Comment: I used the formula $a^x=e^{\ln a^x}=e^{x\ln a}$, and the chain rule for differentiation.

Comment: Why not replace e (and log base e) with some other random number?

Comment: Because then you will get a factor different from one when differentiating. This is one explanation of why $e$ is the natural base to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the exponential function is the unique solution the the equation. Power series expansion can be used to verify.